# Java - Override an object created in Constructor?

Tags: java, spring, constructor, overriding, autowired

In the following Spring service I am creating `ClassToCreate`in the constructor of `MyService`.

```
 @Service("MyService")
 public class MyService {

  private final Repository repository;
  private final ClassToCreate classToCreate;

        @Autowired
        public MyService(
                Repository repository,
                @Value("${path}") String path
                ) {

            this.ClassToCreate = new ClassToCreate(repository, path);
        }

        public void myMethod(Object object){

        String appendedPath = path + object.id();

        //create different instance of classToCreate with variable appended
        ClassToCreate classToCreate = new ClassToCreate(repository, appendedPath);

        classToCreate.doSomething();

        }


    }
```

What is the best way to create and use a different instance of `ClassToCreate` as I am attmempting in `myMethod` rather than use what is in the constuctor?

I want to create a different instance of the class here using the path from constructor but with the object.id appended as the path for `ClassToCreate`. I also need to use the same `repository` value as is passed into the `MyService` constructor.

Comment: What exactly is your issue with your code?

Comment: If you want to change the instance of `ClassToCreate`, it can't be `final`. Just remove `final` modifier

Comment: It is highly not recommended to dynamically change the properties, rather you could inject objects as beans to classToCreate. Did you already try using setter or method lookup bean injection?

Comment: From where will you get path in ```String appendedPath = path + object.id();
```?

Comment: I was hoping to pull path from the  @Value("${path}") String path in the constructor, or is there another better way?

Comment: `ClassToCreate classToCreate = new ClassToCreate(repository, appendedPath);` is a local variable in your method. Yes, you can use local variables with the same name as a field in the object (which you can still access btw, as `this.classToCreate`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use composition. 
You can use a component (@Component in Spring).
Create factory method which returns objects of ClassToCreate.

```
@Component
```

public class ClassToCreateFactory {

```
private Repository repository;
private String path;

@Autowired
public ClassToCreateFactory (Repository repository, @Value("${path}") String path) {
    this.repository = repository;
    this.path = path;
}    

public static ClassToCreate getClassToCreate() {
    return new ClassToCreate(repository, path);
}
```

}

Comment: Would this not need to be static?

Comment: Yes , path has a static value for all instance,  It can be static.